# What happens if extJS trial expires?

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I am using extJS trial to learn. In few days, my trial shall expire. What it really means if trial expires. Does CMD tool stop building extJS or there is something else which I need to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You acknowledge that trial and/or beta software might place watermarks on output, contain limited functionality, function for a limited period of time, or limit the functionality or time of functioning of any output. Access to and/or use of any files or output created with such software is entirely at your own risk. we are licensing the software on an “as is” basis at your own risk and we disclaim any warranty or liability to you of any kind."

https://www.sencha.com/legal/sencha-software-license-agreement/